# How can I fetch metadata or file version (properties details section) of a file on client side?

Tags: javascript, angular, filesystems, filereader, dataview

I am trying to get dll file version on client side only.

Writing code on Angular 16 (2+), any solution on ts/js would work.

I tried using DataView and couple of solutions i found online, though they are returning file version though it is not correct.

```
onSelectFile(event: any) {
  const file2: File = event.target.files[0];
  this.readFile(file2);
}

readFile(file: File) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  reader.onload = (e: any) => {
    const arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
    const version = this.extractVersion(arrayBuffer);
    console.log('DLL Version:', version);
  };
}

extractVersion(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer): string {
  const dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

  // Get the offset of the version information
  const versionOffset = dataView.getUint32(60, true);
  
  // Read the version information from the specified offset
  const majorVersion = dataView.getUint16(versionOffset + 8, true);
  const minorVersion = dataView.getUint16(versionOffset + 10, true);
  const buildNumber = dataView.getUint16(versionOffset + 12, true);
  const revisionNumber = dataView.getUint16(versionOffset + 14, true);
  
  // Construct the version string
  const version = `${majorVersion}.${minorVersion}.${buildNumber}.${revisionNumber}`;
  
  // Print the version
  return version;
}
```

Output I am getting for dll Version is: -

> `DLL Version: 58052.49828.0.0`

If I check the properties and go to details tab, version is something else: -

[image]

Can I know, how to extract the correct fileversion on client side either using DataView or any other class/library?